# optimizer gradient not applied in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently using tensorflow 1.7

For some reason the optimizer gradients are not being applied. Here is my simple code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print("tensorflow version={}".format(tf.__version__))

a= np.zeros((2,2), dtype="float32")
b= np.array([[6,7],[8,9]], dtype="float32")


t1= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2,2))
label_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2,2))

t2 = tf.layers.dense(t1,2, activation=tf.nn.relu)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(t2 - label_t))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    steps=2
    for i in range(steps):
        print("trainop", train_op)
        pred, loss_val, _= sess.run([t2,loss, train_op], feed_dict={t1:a, label_t:b})
        print("pred={}, loss={}".format(pred, loss_val))
```

The output is:

```
trainop name: "Adam"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^Adam/update_dense/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam/update_dense/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam/Assign"
input: "^Adam/Assign_1"

pred=[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]], loss=230.0
trainop name: "Adam"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^Adam/update_dense/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam/update_dense/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam/Assign"
input: "^Adam/Assign_1"

pred=[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]], loss=230.0
```

I have tried separating the `minimize()` into `compute_gradient` and `apply_gradient`. Even so, the gradients do not seem to be applied(loss value remains the same and the trainable variables stay the same).

Can anyone give me a hint on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: replace `relu` activation with `None` i.e. linear layer

Comment: btw grads always equal 0 when input of relu is zero, as result nn learn nothing

Comment: @BugKiller thanks! your solution worked! And really appreciate additional info on the relu problem.

Answer (score 0):

as @BugKiller helped me out in the comments, the cause was my bad choice of activation function. I can see the loss diminishing if I remove the explicit activation assignment. And as @BugKiller has kindly explained in the comments, it was my bad from the beginning to blindly use the `tf.nn.relu` function as the activation function.